# Small confusion: using pointers only to write array program

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm now writing a program to first find smallest element in an array, reverse the array, and then negate the smallest element in the array reversed. This is only using pointers. But, there's no use of integer variables, or array notation similar as arr[1], arr[0], etc. But there's chance to use pointer integers. Here's incomplete code:

```
void reverse_norm(int *arr, const int length) {
  const int *i = arr;
  int *least = *(arr + (length - 1));
  while (i < arr + length) {
    if (*(arr + *i) < least) {
      *least = (arr + *i);
    }
    i++;
  }

}
```

I have many problems here. The first, it's not done. The second, it's very problematic, with bugs and not able to run. There is just the part to find the smallest element.

Comment: Hint : type of `*(arr + (length - 1)` is `int` and `least` is a pointer to an `int`. Assigning a value to a variable of different type is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Any sane compiler should issue 3 warnings for this code. Consider them as errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is the time to learn how to use your debugger. Additionally (or alternatively) you can insert some `printf()` here and there to inspect some interesting variables. -- Well, after you corrected your code so that it compiles without any warning or error, with the highest warning level available.

Comment: The way you have initialised and are using the variable i [in the loop] is problematic. Try using i as a counter only and track the array using the arr variable.

Comment: Simpler expressions/statements, more lines, more temp vars.  Then printf out everything or use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one right way to write the function you need :

```
void reverse_norm(int *arr, const int length) {
    const int *i = arr;
    const int *least = (arr + (length - 1));
    while (i < arr + length) {
        if (*i < *least) {
            least = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("least is %d\n", *least);
}
```

I did not rename any variable since it is not the problem here, but at least `i` should be renamed as something like `current_element`

Comment: Yes, thanks. But how is least  = i; work? When I run it, it's not work. And to get the array element, then I have to use (arr + (i - 1)) no? Sorry I am confused

Comment: `i` is a pointer to the element in the array which is currently evaluated. Since `i` is NOT an integer, `i - 1` is also pointer: to the element just before the one currently evaluated. `arr + ( i - 1)` is adding two pointers : it has no sense. The instruction `least = i` is just making `least`  pointing to the element currently evaluated.